# Firefox 3 Extension JavaScript Duplicated Event Listener on Load

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was fixing up an extension that was written for Firefox 2 to work with Firefox 3.
One of the changes was to use:

```
window.getBrowser().addEventListener("load", checkURL, true);
```

instead of going through just window.

The only problem is that the `load` event seems to occur more than once per page load. I have also tried listening for `DOMContentLoaded` but with similar results.

Is there a way to make sure to execute the script only once per page load? If it matters, the pages I am loading are forum pages from https://forums.somethingawful.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that for one, load events can be triggered by loading images like the favicon. So one must make sure that the target is indeed the document:

```
aEvent.originalTarget.nodeName == "#document"
```

More info can be obtained on the snippets page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/On_page_load

Comment: You may also want to check the condition `aEvent.originalTarget.documentURI == "about:blank"` and do nothing if it is true (user opened a new tab and it's empty)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.getBrowser().addProgressListener(
  checkURL,
  Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT
);
```

and checkLink needs to be an object with onStateChange function with this signature:

```
onStateChange: function(aProgress, request, stateFlags, status);
```

Check out the docs on [nsiWebProgress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIWebProgress).